# How can i register an Event Handler for a custom AplicationEvent in C# .net win Form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, events, eventhandler

I have a method to handle my Custom event.

I am trying to register this method as the event handler for my event.
The method that handles the event needs to be inside a form because it needs to update a form's property(a listview).

I raise the event as follows:

```
// Inside MyForm.cs
ApplicationEvents.Raise(new MyCustomEvent(param1, this.listview));

public class MyCustomEventHandler
    {
        public static void RegisterMyCustomEventHandler()
        {
            var handler = new MyCustomEventHandler();
            ApplicationEvents.Register<MyCustomEvent> 
                (handler.HandleMyCustomEvent);
        }
        public void HandleMyCustomEvent(MyCustomEvent event)
        {
           //code to handle the event
        }
    }
```

Already tried above code, but cannot be applied to my context because I have to raise the application event inside a Task that should update a form control.

Because of that I get cross-threading errors. So I figured I should move the RegisterMytCustomEventhandler and HandleMyCustomEvent methods inside the form code. So my problem now shifted to registering the method as a eventhandler.

```
// inside MyForm class:
public void HandleMyCustomEvent( MyCustomEvent myEvent)
{
   // some code to handle the event.
}

// I tried something like this
public void RegisterMyCustomEventHandler()
   {
      var handler = new MyCustomEventHandler();
      ApplicationEvents.Register<MyCustomEvent> (handler.HandleCustomEvent);
   }

// Program.cs class: 
 static void Main(string[] 
 {
     MyCustomEventhandler.RegisterMyCustomEventHandler();
 }

// And how I raise the exception: 
 ApplicationEvents.Raise(new MyCustomEvent(param1, form.listview));
```